# How the Geometry of periodic homogenization domain works?

Tags: integration, general-topology, partial-differential-equations

I just started reading this paper

[Periodic Unfolding method][1]
[1]: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220132127_The_Periodic_Unfolding_Method_in_Homogenization

where in the definition 1.2: for each $x \in R^{N}$, one has $x = \epsilon( [\frac{x}{\epsilon}]_{Y} + \{\frac{x}{\epsilon}\}_{Y})$ where $[.]$ gives the integer or position of a point in $\Omega$ the open set and $\{.\}$ stands for position in reference cell.\

$Ξε =\{ξ ∈ Z^{N},ε(ξ +Y )⊂Ω\}$, \
$ Ωε = interior\{ \cup_{ξ∈Ξε} \, ε(ξ +Y)\}$,\
$Λε = Ω - Ωε$.\

The set $Ωε$ is the largest union of $ε(ξ + Y)$ cells $(ξ ∈ Z^{n})$ included in $Ω$, while $Λε$ is the subset of Ω containing the parts from ε(ξ+Y)cells intersecting the boundary ∂Ω.

Then in the proof of preposition 2.5 I am missing the point how?
$|εξ +εY|\int_{Y} φ(εξ +εy)dy = ε^{n}|Y| \int_{Y} φ(εξ +εy) dy $.

If someone just skip his or her 2 minutes please. Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this due to the periodicity of the domain? as written "  In $R^{N}$,let $Ω$ be an open set and $Y$ a reference cell (e.g$., ]0,1[^{n} $, or more generally, a set having the paving property, with respect to a basis $( b_{1},...,b_{n}) $ deﬁning the periods).

Comment: So can I say $ | \epsilon \xi + \epsilon Y| = | \epsilon Y| = \epsilon^{N} |Y|$ ????

Comment: $|\cdot|$ refers to the Lebesgue measure.  By translation invariance, $|\epsilon \xi + \epsilon Y| = |\epsilon Y|$ and scaling gives $|\epsilon Y| = \epsilon^{N} |Y|$.

Comment: Thank You So much @PeterMorfe